# determine if an array contains all elements of another array often enough?

Tags: ruby

I have an Array with available elements and an Array with required elements. I want to find out if all required elements are available.

The Arrays may contain "duplicates". Then there must be as many elements available as required. My first trial for a #contains? method fails because include? checks only 
if an element is available at least once

-- edit: simplified example code --

```
# a first and simple trial
# that fails on duplicate elements
class Array
  def contains?(other)
    other.all? { |element| include?(element) }      
  end      
end

available = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
small = [1, 1, 2, 3]  
big = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3] 

available.contains?(small) # is true as intended
available.contains?(big)   # is true but should be false
                           # because "big" contains more "3s" than "available"
```

Comment: please put some examples,and expected output with the scenarios will be helpful to answer you first. your full code is confusing.. put only the relevant part,which is not working..I didn't understand *Then there must be as many elements available as required*.another confusion *he Arrays may contain "duplicates".* - which array you are talking about ? Why your current `#contains?` will not work as you said *#too simple, doesn't reflect duplicate elements* ?

Comment: for each required element, check if the element is in `available`, if so then remove it from `available`. repeat for all required elements.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. Maybe it was be a bad idea to pack the two examples in a spec?

Comment: I think the main reason people dislike it is because you didn't trim down your question to the minimum relevant parts. What is crucial to your question is comparing two arrays. You should not have shown your `Container` class. And you introduced the attribute `elements` without any explanation. That was bad. I had to guess what that meant.

Comment: Simplified the example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def contains?(other)
  other.elements.group_by{|e| e}.all?{|e, a| elements.count(e) >= a.length}
end
```

Comment: Amazing. It was downvoted within **one second** after I posted this answer.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe you should have posted it earlier? :-) I've given up trying to figure out the downvoters; I think they must have a surplus of points and are trying to burn some off. I gave you a +1 to balance out the universe.